# Kibana Fails to start : FATAL { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I downloaded on the windows machine and instantiated the Elastic search and also tried to instantiate Kibana, but received the error message - Kibana Fails to start : FATAL { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory}

Please guide